# Generate Random variates with a certain Probability density function by python

Tags: python, random, scipy, distribution

I want to generate a random variate with maxwell energy(e.g. f(ene)) or arbitrary distribution.
The probablily density function is like :

```
def f(ene):  
     le=3  
     return 2(ene/pi/le**3)*np.exp(-ene/le)
```

I would like to generate 10000 samples like

```
f.rvs(scale,size)
```

which generate a list includes 10000 elements which density function is match on f(ene)

## How could I do it?

Example:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html
scipy provide a maxwell distribution:
with method: rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=1)    Random variates.

```
print maxwell.rvs(1,10000)
```

will generate 10000 sample with maxwell distribution. But scipy only provide some functions. Now I have another function not in scipy's . How could I do that?

Comment: what is the `f.rvs(scale, size)` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: That didn't really clear things up for me.  It's late in the day and I'm probably not thinking correctly, but `scale` would what?  I'm assuming `size` is the 10,000 samples.

Comment: Let me give example:

Comment: To define a continuous distribution that you can use like other scipy.stats distributions, given a probability density function that you specify, you want something like http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.

Comment: This is far too broad a question.  There are entire books written about how to generate from various distributions, and while there are some generalized techniques any given approach isn't going to work for all distributions.

Comment: Do you recognize your distribution is probably wrong? It is derived from Maxwell for speed and looks like converted from speed to energy (ene=mv^2/2), but Jacobian is NOT here

Comment: @  Severin Pappadeux What's wrong with distribution?

Comment: I'd better write an answer, it would be long. Check in an hour or so

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets start with distribution.

Probability density function for speed is

```
PDF(v) = sqrt(2/PI)*v^2*exp(-v^2/2a^2)/a^3
```

Lets convert it from speed to energy, considering E=v^2/2 (and assume mass is equal to 1)

```
PDF(E) = sqrt(2/PI)*2*E*exp(-E/a^2)/a^3
```

Looks ok? No, it is wrong. Why? Because PDF times the interval gives you probability, and we didn't convert interval. Probability for speed was
`PDF(v) * dv`, and we have to insert Jacobian

```
PDF(E)*dE = sqrt(2/PI)*2*E*exp(-E/a^2)/a^3 * |dv/dE| * dE

|dv/dE| = 1/|dE/dv| = 1/v = 1 / sqrt(2*E)
```

All together

```
PDF(E) = 2*sqrt(1/PI)*sqrt(E)*exp(-E/a^2)/a^3
```

where `a=sqrt(k*T)`

Your distribution is missing `sqrt(E)`

How I would sample it. I would use the fact that it is actually product of three independent 1D distribution

```
PDF(vx) = 1/sqrt(2*PI)*exp(-vx^2/2a^2)
PDF(vy) = 1/sqrt(2*PI)*exp(-vy^2/2a^2)
PDF(vz) = 1/sqrt(2*PI)*exp(-vz^2/2a^2)
```

which means they are all Gaussian. So simple algorithm: sample `vx` from gaussian with mean equal to 0 and sigma equal to `a`, sample `vy` independently from the same distribution, sample `vz` and combine them all together

```
v = sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2)
```

or if you need sampled energy

```
E = ( vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2 )/ 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In the past few years, nice new tools have been added to SciPy to address this kind of problem in Python.
You can easily generate samples from custom continuous or discrete univariate distributions by just providing some information about the distribution, such as the density / pdf.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.sampling import NumericalInversePolynomial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad


class MyDist:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def support(self):
        # distribution restricted to 0, 5, can be changed as needed
        return (0, 5)

    def pdf(self, x):
        # this is not a proper pdf, the normalizing
        # constant is missing (does not integrate to one)
        return x * (x + np.sin(5*x) + 2) * np.exp(-x**self.a)


dist = MyDist(0.5)
gen = NumericalInversePolynomial(dist)

# compute the missing normalizing constant to plot the pdf
const_pdf = quad(dist.pdf, *dist.support())[0]

r = gen.rvs(size=50000)
x = np.linspace(r.min(), r.max(), 500)

# show histogram together with the pdf
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x) / const_pdf)
plt.hist(r, density=True, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: Samples and density]

Overview of the different methods:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.sampling.html

Tutorial:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/sampling.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I can come up with, but I'm not confident on what you're trying to do here:

```
import numpy as np

def f(ene):
    le = 3
    return 2 * (ene / np.pi / le ** 3) * np.exp(-ene / le)

def rvs(scale, size):
    samples = np.random.sample((size,))
    return scale * f(samples)
```

I got this as a result.  Obviously this will be different each time as this is randomized.

```
In:  print(rvs(100, 10))
Out: [ 1.56035154  0.85509302  0.76543496  1.36966862  0.20596924  0.0395071
  1.35029318  0.69437599  0.59772671  0.56721737]
```

Comment: The original question was confusing because it uses notation specific to scipy.stats, and I think it was asking something slightly different than this answer gives.  This answer evaluates the provided pdf at some uniformly distributed points on the unit interval.  I think the question wants some samples distributed according to their provided pdf, which is a different thing.